# Submit without refresh in php

Tags: php, javascript

I've read a lot of post regarding the topic. I've seen lots of answers and pointing to use ajax. Is there any other way to not refresh the page on form submit?

E.g Sample form

```
<form method="post">
<input type="radio" name="test" value="Start">Start<br />
<input type="radio" name="test" value="Stop">Stop<br />
<input type="submit" value="GO">
</form>
```

Is there a javascript way of doing it without using ajax and jquery?

Thanks,

Comment: No. Like you already answered, use ajax.

Comment: you need to use either jquery or ajax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use iframes:

```
<iframe id="myIframe" name="myIframe" width="0" height="0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<form method="post" target="myIframe" action="script.php">
    <input type="radio" name="test" value="Start">Start<br />
    <input type="radio" name="test" value="Stop">Stop<br />
    <input type="submit" value="GO">
</form>
```

Comment: you need action for your script, and target for iframe

Comment: Note that iframes are not made for these operations and iframes lower your pagespeed. Just use AJAX for these operations. I know you say you dont want AJAX, but you mention the `javascript` tag so I guess you dont understand AJAX...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a form embedded in an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may use AJAX For that it's better ways to submit form without page refresh

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" onSubmit="event.preventDefault()">
<input type="radio" name="test" value="Start">Start<br />
<input type="radio" name="test" value="Stop">Stop<br />
<input type="submit" value="GO">
</form>
```

You don't need to use any iframe for this short purpose... as you looking for a javascript methods, I will recommend you to use `event.preventDefault()` inside the `form` tag in html... it will not let the form submitted and refresh the page...

Comment: I can't use that one because i need to submit the form. using that one i don't get any output.